# Reasons of computing smallest eigenvalue $R^TR$ instead of singular value

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd, cross-product

I have problems in understanding why author of this [article](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2013/papers/Kneip_Direct_Optimization_of_2013_ICCV_paper.pdf) uses smallest eigenvalue of a cross product matrix instead of a data matrix. I know that $SVD(AA^T)=UD^2U^T$, but I don't know why not compute $SVD(A)=UDV^T$ and square the smallest value $\lambda_{min}$. Due to measurement and computation inaccuracies, the smallest eigenvalue is then minimized (preferably to $0$).

Comment: They are equivalent, but computing the smallest eigenvalue can be done without computing an entire factorization which may be more efficient

Comment: So, besides the philosophy around defining the problem to minimize distances, is the sole reason computational?